# Unitriangular matrices act trivially on quotients of the standard flag

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

In their book Fundamentals of the Theory of Group, Kargapolov and Merzljakov state upon proving Kaluznin's theorem in chapter six that, "...matrices of given size over a given field are ... automorphisms of a vector space with a given basis, and from this point of view the unitriangular matrices are just those automorphisms fixing each member of a descending chain of subspaces spanned by subsets of the basis, and acting trivially on the factors of the chain."

Indeed the unitriangular matrices stabilize the standard flag. How do they act on factors of that flag? How can we see that they act trivially on those factors?

Comment: What did you try to solve this? Did you try 2-dimensional case first? It is very straightforward. Once you understand 2d case, try induction on the dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V \subseteq W$ are subspaces and $G$ acts on $W$ and $GV \subseteq V$ (i.e. $G$ stabilizes $V$) then the quotient $W/V$ has a natural $G$ action defined by $g\cdot(w + V) = (g\cdot w) + V$.  You should check for yourself that this is well defined, meaning it doesn't depend on the representative $w$ that I choose for $w + V$.

In the case of unitriangular matrices you then just have to check that
$$g\cdot e_i \in e_i + \mathrm{span}\{e_{i + 1}, \ldots, e_n\}$$
(in fact this should be obvious as $g\cdot e_i$ is just the $i^\text{th}$ column of $g$).  When you compute the action on the quotient you'll see that this means $g$ fixes the element $e_i + \mathrm{span}\{e_{i + 1}, \ldots, e_n\}$ in
$$\mathrm{span}\{e_i, \ldots, e_n\}/\mathrm{span}\{e_{i + 1}, \ldots, e_n\}.$$